# What is better - store player's inventory in JSON(text field in database) or database directly?

Tags: python, mysql, json, database

I'm creating a little own game, and I need to solve the problem: where I need to store player's inventory: in database with JSON(text field) or directly in database tables. Which method consume less RAM, and which is faster at all?
Game server will be written on Python

Comment: Will the inventory ever need to be written to disk?  (i.e. will your game have a "save" command, or is the game always played start-to-finish in one session?)

Comment: best is in key-value pair in memory for caching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your required requirements i preferred you to use NoSQL database e.g `Mongo`with implementation of `redis`for memory data storage that gives you more flexibility and performance.It based on objects so helps you for fetching faster

Answer (score 1):

It's probably better to use database tables directly.  That way you can take advantage of other database features such as foreign keys, unique constraints, triggers, and so on.